# how to find difference between two image

Tags: java, image, frame

Is there any software or code that can help me capture difference between two similar image frames?

For eg:
there is a an image of a guy with a cap

and another image of the same guy without a cap

everything else is same in the image

so can i get a third image which will have only the cap? which is the difference between the two images

Answer (score 1):

I've used artificial neural networks for such problems. But the solution is too complicated to explain here. I suggest the ML course on Coursera.

Answer (score 0):

Just use OpenCV to threshold the images. And you will get only that information which differs.